# Find tangency of InterpolatingFunction and circle

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

I am trying to use a system of equations to solve for the common tangent of a (polar) InterpolatingFunction and a circle.  Unfortunately, both NSolve and FindRoot don't yield results, even when I "hand-feed" values into the equations into the equations (i.e. in combinations of equations 1,3,4 / 2,3,4 or 1,2,3)

My guess is that this may have to do with "excessive" precision, although I'm not sure.

Question: what function would I best use to get the closest approximations, if it is a precision problem?  For my purposes, three decimal places would be sufficient.

(If someone sees a better basic geometric strategy to go at the problem, please do say.)

Please have a look at the graphic and the code:

[image: diagram]

```
(* intf[ang1] is the InterpolatingFunction (green),
rotated about {0,0} until it is tangent to the circle.
Goal: find out ang1, ang3, angrotation *)

intpoints = {{0, 17.9817}, {0.0521424, 18.5701}, {0.105454, 
    19.1892}, {0.15991, 19.8416}, {0.215494, 20.5299}, {0.272199, 
    21.2567}, {0.330029, 22.0243}, {0.388993, 22.8348}, {0.449111, 
    23.6897}, {0.510411, 24.5896}, {0.572931, 25.5338}, {0.636716, 
    26.5201}, {0.701823, 27.5438}, {0.76832, 28.5972}, {0.836286, 
    29.6684}, {0.905813, 30.7409}, {0.977011, 31.7919}, {1.05, 
    32.7921}, {1.12493, 33.7052}, {1.20195, 34.4887}, {1.28123, 
    35.0956}, {1.36295, 35.4775}, {1.44731, 35.5905}};
intf = Interpolation[intpoints]

(* values used in example *)
r1 = 9.5;
x1 = 34.2584;
y1 = 12;

(* 1. parametric equations for a circle of radius R1 with center \
located at {X1,Y1} *)
xcirclefn[ang2_] = r1*Cos[ang2] + x1;
ycirclefn[ang2_] = r1*Sin[ang2] + y1;

(* 2. equations for locating points based on rotation of axes of intf \
*)
xintf[ang1_] = intf[ang1]*Cos[ang1];
yintf[ang1_] = intf[ang1]*Sin[ang1];
xrot[ang1_, angrotation_] = 
  xintf[ang1]*Cos[angrotation] - yintf[ang1]*Sin[angrotation];
yrot[ang1_, angrotation_] = 
  xintf[ang1]*Sin[angrotation] + yintf[ang1]*Cos[angrotation];

(* 3. equations for angles of tangents *)
slopecircle[ang2_] = ycirclefn'[ang2]/xcirclefn'[ang2] ;
angleang3c[ang2_] = ArcTan[-1/slopecircle[ang2]] ;

slopeintf[ang1_] = yintf'[ang1]/xintf'[ang1];
angleang3i[ang1_, angrotation_] = 
  ArcTan[-1/slopeintf[ang1]] + angrotation;
(* angrotation is negative *)

(* Possible identities: *)
equation1 = xcirclefn[ang2] == xrot[ang1, angrotation];
equation2 = ycirclefn[ang2] == yrot[ang1, angrotation];
equation3 = angleang3c[ang2] == angleang3i[ang1, angrotation];
equation4 = intf[ang1] == Sqrt[xcirclefn[ang2]^2 + ycirclefn[ang2]^2];

(* CAD-measured values in radians:
ang1 = 0.714321 (CCW from intf[0.])
 ang2 = 3.09004 (CCW from 0.)
angrotation = -0.247318 (CW from 0.)
ang3 = -(2*Pi)+(Pi/2 + (-0.0515572)) = -4.76395 (CW from 0.) (1.51924 included angle) *)

(* Method 1:
NSolve[equation1&&equation2&&equation3,{ang1,ang2,angrotation}] *)

(* Method 2:
FindRoot[{equation1,equation3,equation4},{{ang1,0},{ang2,0},{\
angrotation,-Pi/2}}] *)
```

Comment: Could you complete your example with the interpolating function and the solving approaches you already tested?

And maybe, if possible, switch to lowercase symbol names throughout? Uppercase sometimes collides with predefined symbols, causing all kinds of "surprising" behavior.

Comment: You might also want to define your functions using `:=` (`SetDelayed`).

Comment: Depending on the `Interpolation` you used, there might not be a usable derivative. See the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) for examples.

Comment: If you could provide me with your `intf`, I might be able to help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand, anyway:

```
intpoints = {{0, 17.9817}, {0.0521424, 18.5701}, {0.105454, 19.1892}, {0.15991, 19.8416}, 
            {0.215494, 20.5299}, {0.272199, 21.2567}, {0.330029, 22.0243}, {0.388993, 22.8348}, 
            {0.449111, 23.6897}, {0.510411, 24.5896}, {0.572931, 25.5338}, {0.636716, 26.5201}, 
            {0.701823, 27.5438}, {0.76832, 28.5972}, {0.836286,  29.6684}, {0.905813, 30.7409}, 
            {0.977011, 31.7919}, {1.05, 32.7921}, {1.12493, 33.7052}, {1.20195, 34.4887}, 
            {1.28123,  35.0956}, {1.36295, 35.4775}, {1.44731, 35.5905}};
intf = Interpolation[intpoints]

(*values used in example*)
r1 = 9.5; x1 = 34.2584; y1 = 12;
exp = RotationMatrix[-ang1].(intf[p] {Cos@p, Sin@p});
sol = NMinimize[{ang1, EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, exp] == r1 && 0 < p < Pi/2}, {p,  ang1}];
Show[ContourPlot[(x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2 == r1^2, {x, 0, 50}, {y, -10, 40}], 
     ParametricPlot[intf[p] {Cos@p, Sin@p}, {p, 0, Pi/2}], 
     ParametricPlot[exp /. sol[[2]], {p, 0.01, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Jinxed: info added, thanks!

Comment: belisarius: thanks, will try adapting this method and see if I can pull the angles out. Looks much cleaner than mine.

Comment: @jharrison There you have it done

Comment: I started fresh and copied your code, and got: NMinimize::nsol: There are no points that satisfy the constraints {}. >>

Comment: @jharrison: Same for me.

Comment: @Jinxed: if I use the EuclideanDistance[{x1,y1}...] == r1 as a solver equation, and hand-feed it a value for p, NSolve then successfully finds the corresponding RotationMatrix angle in a snap. Hmmm.

Comment: @Jinxed: belisarius is apparently running v9 (see comments in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75704/integral-does-not-converge-when-it-should).  I was using v10, but just tried the NMinimize in v9 and it works.

Comment: @jharrison Yup.V9 here. Sorry, I can't test it on v10.

Comment: Hmm - another v10-oddity. :( My approach was based on solving for curve-circle-coincidence, but that did produce weird results, also. I am still investigating why that might be.

Comment: I'm good with this solution, will stay in v9 for the nonce.

Comment: @jharrison Good to know :). Please re-read the following comment

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!