# Integral does not converge (when it should)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

I was looking at integrals like:

```
Integrate[HermiteH[50, x]*Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

which gave me a "does not converge on $(0,\infty)$" error. On the other hand something like

```
Integrate[(x^50)*Exp[-x^2]], {x, 0, Infinity}]
Integrate[HermiteH[4,x]*Exp[-x^2]], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

works just fine. In general, for $n\geq 16$, $\int_0^\infty H_n(x)e^{-x^2}dx$ is reported as divergent.

Is there an easy way to resolve this bug?

I should mention that I'm using Mathematica 10.0.0.0.

Comment: It returns zero on Mma v9

Comment: @belisarius: I know, you get zero for even $n$, and not zero for odd $n$. But it should very well converge for any $n$. Did i maybe change an option somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have v10 around so I can't test your problem

Comment: Works fine in 10.0.2.  Always upgrade to the latest point release.  Lots of bugs got fixed since 10.0.0, and 10.0.0 has a reputation for being pretty buggy ...

Comment: Works fine in 10.0.2 for me as well, so probably a 10.0.0-specific bug.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Silly me for thinking it auto-updates. Thanks! Problem resolved.

Comment: @AlexR. So you tested in 10.0.2 and now it works for you as well?  Just to make sure it was really due to the version difference and not something else ...

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yep, I updated to 10.0.2 and it works. I tried resetting 10.0.0 but still had the same bug.

Comment: @Alex R. it returns 0 very quickly in version 8.

Comment: Probably duplicates: [(61866)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61866), [(65120)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65120)

Answer (score 1):

Integrating each term separately obtains the desired result:

```
Integrate[#, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] & /@ 
  Expand[HermiteH[50, x] Exp[-x^2]]
```

results in `0`.

If each term of the integral is convergent, the whole integral must be convergent, so this must be a bug.

Comment: I tried using Expand in 10.0.0 but it produced the same error.

Comment: Interesting... I can duplicate your problem in my version (10.0.0.0, `$Version == "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"`), but this solution solves it.  Which of the terms is it giving `Integrate::idiv` for?

Comment: I'm on iOS. I tend to get divergence errors for $n\geq 15$ of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n(x)e^{-x^2}dx$

Comment: When you integrate term-by-term (using my code above) for, say, `n = 16`, which of the terms are divergent?

Comment: I'm actually not sure because I upgraded to 10.0.2 which fixed the error. Before using Expand I had: Integrate[Expand[Hermite[20,x]]*Exp[-x^2],{x,0,Infinity}] and that didn't work.

Comment: `HermiteH` already returns an expanded polynomial, so `Expand` does nothing to it.  My code uses `Expand` to multiply the exponential by each term individually, and then uses `Map` to integrate each of those terms separately.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using assumptions? Using assumptions with version 10.0.0, I get the same results as with version 10.0.2

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"

```
Clear[f]

f[n_Integer] = Integrate[HermiteH[n, x]*Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> {Element[n, Integers]}]
```

> (2^(-1 + n)*Sqrt[Pi])/Gamma[1 - n/2]

```
Integrate[HermiteH[n, x]*Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[    (2^n*(-2 + n)*Sqrt[Pi]*
>           Hypergeometric2F1[1, (1 - n)/2, 
>             1/2, 1])/(n*Gamma[-(n/2)]),     NotElement[n, Integers] && 
>        Re[n] > 0]

However, assuming the stated conditions gives the same result as the integer case

```
f[n_] = Integrate[HermiteH[n, x]*Exp[-x^2], {x, 0, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> {NotElement[n, Integers] && Re[n] > 0}]
```

> (2^(-1 + n)*Sqrt[Pi])/Gamma[1 - n/2]

Combining the results

```
Clear[f]

f[n_] = (2^(-1 + n)*Sqrt[Pi])/Gamma[1 - n/2];

Simplify[f[2 n], {Element[n, Integers], n > 0}] // Quiet
```

> 0

```
Show[
 Plot[f[n], {n, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All],
 DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, -5, 5}]]
```

[image]

```
Table[{n, f[n]}, {n, -5, 50}]
```

> {{-5, 1/120}, {-4, Sqrt[Pi]/64},     {-3, 1/12}, {-2, Sqrt[Pi]/8},
>   {-1, 1/2}, {0, Sqrt[Pi]/2},     {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, -2}, {4, 0},
>   {5, 12}, {6, 0}, {7, -120},     {8, 0}, {9, 1680}, {10, 0},     {11,
>   -30240}, {12, 0},     {13, 665280}, {14, 0},     {15, -17297280}, {16, 0},     {17, 518918400}, {18, 0},     {19, -17643225600}, {20, 0},
>   {21, 670442572800}, {22, 0},     {23, -28158588057600}, {24, 0},
>   {25, 1295295050649600}, {26, 0},     {27, -64764752532480000},
>   {28, 0}, {29, 
>        3497296636753920000}, {30, 0},     {31, -202843204931727360000},     {32, 0}, {33, 
>        12576278705767096320000},     {34, 0}, {35, 
>        -830034394580628357120000},     {36, 0}, {37, 
>        58102407620643984998400000},     {38, 0}, {39, 
>        -4299578163927654889881600000},     {40, 0}, {41, 
>        335367096786357081410764800000},     {42, 0}, {43, 
>        -2750010193648128067568271360000\
>       0}, {44, 0}, {45, 
>        23650087665373901381087133696000\    00}, {46,    0}, {47, -212850788988365\
>       112429784203264000000}, {48, 0},     {49, 2000797416490632056839971510\    6816000000}, {50, 0}}